# Is there a way to optimize repeated large amounts of Process invocations?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, python-tesseract, .net-7.0

I have a function that calls a Python executable (that processes files) using the `Process` class:

```
public static async Task<string> executePythonAsync(string cmd,
 string path, string tessbindata, string name, bool? primaryOrSecondary,
 bool? meleeOrGrenade)
        {
            string startTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff");
            var watch = sd.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            string POS = primaryOrSecondary?.ToString() ?? "k";
            string MOG = meleeOrGrenade?.ToString() ?? "k";

            ProcessStartInfo start = new(cmd,
 string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", path, tessbindata, POS, MOG));

            start.UseShellExecute = false;
            start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            if (start != null)
            {
                using (Process process = Process.Start(start) ?? Process.Start(
new ProcessStartInfo(cmd, string.Format("{0} {1}", path, tessbindata))))
                {
                    if (process != null)
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                        {
                            Task<string> result = reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                            string final = result + result.Result;
                            return result;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return ("Failed. Time = " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff") + ".");
            //Process.Start(start);
        }
```

However, this method takes a long while to fully execute completely (~20 seconds, and can be called as many as 600 times) and I want to grab the result of this without waiting 4 hours just to discover that the data is corrupted/lost/etc. so I want to make this as fast as possible.

**It is important to note that the method works on several different categories and I want to keep them separate:**

```
private static List<string> assaultRiflesStrings = new() {
                "ak12","an94","as-val","scar-l","aug-a1","m16a4","g36","m16a1","m16a3","type-20","aug-a2","k2","famas-f1",
                "ak47","aug-a3","l85a2","hk416","ak74","akm","ak103","tar-21","type-88","m231","c7a2","stg-44","g11k2" };

private static List<string> personalDefenseWeaponsStrings = new() {
                "mp5k","ump45","g36c","mp7","mac10","p90","colt-mars","mp5","colt-smg-633","l2a3","mp5sd","mp10","m3a1",
                "mp510","uzi","aug-a3-para-xs","k7","ak74u","ppsh-41","fal-para-shorty","kriss-vector","pp-19-bizon","mp40",
                "x95-smg","tommy-gun","rama-1130"};

private static List<string> lightMachineGunsStrings = new() {
                "colt-lmg","m60","aug-hbar","mg36","rpk12","l86-lsw","rpk","hk21e","hamr-iar","rpk74","mg3kws" };
```

So now, I have a bunch of data that I want to process, and I want it to be run as fast as possible.

My first solution was to just run the whole thing in one thread, but that took hours and I do not want to spend all that time just running the code.

My second solution was to try multithreading **all** the categories like so: (note that this doesn't have asynchronous yet, but the first thing I tried)

```
Thread ARS = new(() => executePythonAsync( ...all the strings in the AssaultRiflesStrings...);
Thread PDWS = new(() => executePythonAsync( ...all the strings in the PersonalDefenseWeaponsStrings...);
...and so on...
```

However this method runs up to **19 threads** and my CPU is unfortunately not capable of fully utilizing the CPU power to process all of these at once, making it slower.

My third solution is to combine multithreading and asynchronous programming so that in one thread:

1. The first category would be processed and go to a `List<string>` that contains all the outputs of the first category.
2. After the first category has **completely finished**, the second category would then start, outputting exactly like the first.

The code I have now looks like this:

```
private Dictionary<BuildOptions, 
Dictionary<int, FileProcessing.WeaponOutputs>> result = new();

public async Task<Dictionary<BuildOptions,
 Dictionary<int, FileProcessing.WeaponOutputs>>> 
OptimizedBuild(BuildOptions options)
        {

            Thread MainThread = Thread.CurrentThread;

            Func<BuildOptions, int, bool> decoder = (en, id) => 
((int)en & id) != 0;

            bool DMRS = false, LMGS = false, OHBE = false;
            if (decoder(options, (int)BuildOptions.DMRS)) DMRS = true;
            if (decoder(options, (int)BuildOptions.LMGS)) LMGS = true;
            if (decoder(options, (int)BuildOptions.OHBE)) OHBE = true;

            bool BRS = false, SHS = false, MPS = false,
 OTH = false, FGS = false, HEGS = false;
            if (decoder(options, (int)BuildOptions.BRS)) BRS = true;
            if (decoder(options, (int)BuildOptions.SHS)) SHS = true;
            if (decoder(options, (int)BuildOptions.MPS)) MPS = true;
            if (decoder(options, (int)BuildOptions.OTH)) OTH = true;
            if (decoder(options, (int)BuildOptions.FGS)) FGS = true;
            if (decoder(options, (int)BuildOptions.HEGS)) HEGS = true;

            bool OHBT = false, IGS = false, SRS = false, RES = false;
            if (decoder(options, (int)BuildOptions.OHBT)) OHBT = true;
            if (decoder(options, (int)BuildOptions.IGS)) IGS = true;
            if (decoder(options, (int)BuildOptions.SRS)) SRS = true;
            if (decoder(options, (int)BuildOptions.RES)) RES = true;

            bool PDWS = false, CAS = false;
            if (decoder(options, (int)BuildOptions.PDWS)) PDWS = true;
            if (decoder(options, (int)BuildOptions.CAS)) CAS = true;

            bool ARS = false, PS = false;
            if (decoder(options, (int)BuildOptions.ARS)) ARS = true;
            if (decoder(options, (int)BuildOptions.PS)) PS = true;

            bool THBT = false, THBE = false;
            if (decoder(options, (int)BuildOptions.THBT)) THBT = true;
            if (decoder(options, (int)BuildOptions.THBE)) THBE = true;

            /*Func<bool, bool, bool, bool, 
Dictionary<BuildOptions, Dictionary<int, FileProcessing.WeaponOutputs>>> func3 = 
(OHBT, IGS, SRS, RES) => thread3Async(
OHBT, IGS, SRS, RES).Result;*/

            Thread T1 = new(async () => await thread1Async(DMRS, LMGS, OHBE));
            Thread T2 = new(async () => await thread2Async(BRS, SHS,
 MPS, OTH, FGS, HEGS));
            Thread T3 = new(async () => await thread3Async(OHBT, IGS, SRS, RES));
            Thread T4 = new(async () => await thread4Async(PDWS, CAS));
            Thread T5 = new(async () => await thread5Async(ARS, PS));
            Thread T6 = new(async () => await thread6Async(THBT,THBE));

            /*ThreadStart start = new(async () => 
await thread3Async(OHBT, IGS, SRS, RES));*/


            /*Func<Dictionary<BuildOptions,
 Dictionary<int, FileProcessing.WeaponOutputs>>> t3A = 
start.Method.CreateDelegate<Func<Dictionary<BuildOptions,
 Dictionary<int, FileProcessing.WeaponOutputs>>>>(thread3Async(
OHBT, IGS, SRS, RES).Result);*/

            T1.Name = nameof(T1);
            T2.Name = nameof(T2);
            T3.Name = nameof(T3);
            T4.Name = nameof(T4);
            T5.Name = nameof(T5);
            T6.Name = nameof(T6);

            if(DMRS || LMGS || OHBE)T1.Start();
            if(BRS || SHS || MPS || OTH || FGS || HEGS)T2.Start();
            if(OHBT || IGS || SRS || RES)T3.Start();
            if(PDWS || CAS)T4.Start();
            if(ARS || PS)T5.Start();
            if(THBT || THBE)T6.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("damnit");
            return result;


            //) thread1Async().Start();

        }
```

(Ignore the specific return types and all that, all I'm focused about is getting the results of the strings)

For context, the `threadNAsync` methods simply call `executePythonAsync` (in order) with a bunch more irrelevant code that doesn't pertain to the main issue. The booleans are the categories of the strings, and there are 19 of them.

However, there are 2 really big issues with the above code:

1. The main thread "runs away" from the child threads and doesn't wait for the response, so when I call for the output, it gives me an empty list. I want the main thread to wait until the processing has been finished:
   [image: output of the program]
2. The outputs are really hard to get: I cannot use ref or out on an asynchronous method, and I don't know how to get the return values from the methods from the inside of a thread other than adding to a static field and then returning that string (which doesn't work at all because of issue number 1).

How to avoid these issues?

Below is the python code I am trying to use:

```
from queue import Full
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\peter\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\localcache\\local-packages\\python39\\site-packages')

import numpy
import cv2
import pytesseract
import os



# 1560, 300  \ 1840, 630
#   -> 300:330, 1560:280 
# 1260, 400  \  1540, 765
#   -> 400:365, 1260:280

TESS_PATH = sys.argv[2] + "tessbin"
os.environ["TESSDATA_PREFIX"] = TESS_PATH + "\\tessdata\\"
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = TESS_PATH + "\\tesseract"

def unsharp_mask(image, kernel_size=(5, 5), sigma=1.0, amount=8.0, threshold=0.3):
    """Return a sharpened version of the image, using an unsharp mask."""
    #print(type(image))
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, kernel_size, sigma)
    sharpened = float(amount + 1) * image - float(amount) * blurred
    sharpened = numpy.maximum(sharpened, numpy.zeros(sharpened.shape))
    sharpened = numpy.minimum(sharpened, 255 * numpy.ones(sharpened.shape))
    sharpened = sharpened.round().astype(numpy.uint8)
    if threshold > 0:
        low_contrast_mask = numpy.absolute(image - blurred) < threshold
        numpy.copyto(sharpened, image, where=low_contrast_mask)
    return sharpened

def thin_font(image):
    kernel = numpy.ones((3,3),numpy.uint8)
    erode = cv2.erode(image, kernel, iterations=1)
    return (erode)


class ImageParser:
    def __init__(self):
        self.resize_scale = 5
    
    def parse_screenshot(self, fullscreen_image, primary, melee):
        crops = self.crop_fullscreen(fullscreen_image, primary, melee)
        for crop in crops:
            print("=" * 5, crop[0], "=" * 5)
            data = ""

            if crop[0] == "General2":
                data = self.text_from_image(crop[1], "true", melee)
            data = self.text_from_image(crop[1], "false", melee)

            print(data + "\n")
            #file1 = open(r"dataOut.txt","w")
            #file1.write(data)
    
    def crop_fullscreen(self, fullscreen_image, primary, melee):
        if type(fullscreen_image) is str:
            fullscreen_image = cv2.imread(fullscreen_image)

        crops = []
        

        if primary == "True": #primaries
            
            w_crop = fullscreen_image[160:370,1560:1840]
            y_crop = fullscreen_image[430:640, 1560:1840]

            v_crop = fullscreen_image[70:280, 1560:1840]
            b_crop = fullscreen_image[130:335, 1260:1540]
            a_crop = fullscreen_image[380:585, 1260:1540]
            c_crop = fullscreen_image[580:785, 1260:1540]
            
            crops.append(("Top", v_crop))
            crops.append(("General1", w_crop))
            crops.append(("General2", y_crop))
            crops.append(("Ballistics", b_crop))
            crops.append(("Advanced1", a_crop))
            crops.append(("Advanced2", c_crop))

            print("hi im a primary\n")

        elif primary == "False": #secondaries

            w_crop = fullscreen_image[160:350, 1560:1840]
            y_crop = fullscreen_image[420:600, 1560:1840]
            
            v_crop = fullscreen_image[70:280, 1560:1840]
            b_crop = fullscreen_image[130:335, 1260:1540]
            a_crop = fullscreen_image[380:585, 1260:1540]
            c_crop = fullscreen_image[580:785, 1260:1540]
            
            crops.append(("Top", v_crop))
            crops.append(("General1", w_crop))
            crops.append(("General2", y_crop))
            crops.append(("Ballistics", b_crop))
            crops.append(("Advanced1", a_crop))
            crops.append(("Advanced2", c_crop))

            print("hi im a secondary\n")

        else:
            if melee == "True": #melees
                #do something
                s_crop = fullscreen_image[0:180,1560:1840]
                k_crop = fullscreen_image[180:380,1560:1840]
                x_crop = fullscreen_image[380:580,1560:1840]
                
                crops.append(("Top", s_crop))
                crops.append(("General1", k_crop))
                crops.append(("General2", x_crop))

            elif melee == "False": #grenades
                r_crop = fullscreen_image[80:260, 1560:1840]
                j_crop = fullscreen_image[215:430, 1560:1840] #can be changed to 230
                
                crops.append(("Top", r_crop))
                crops.append(("General", j_crop))
        
        #160:370
        

        #500:700
        return crops

    
    
    def text_from_image(self, image, general2, melee):
        if type(image) is str:
            image = cv2.imread(image)
        print(type(image))
        if image.size is 0:
            return "[OCR] Empty Image"
        bw = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        dim = (int(bw.shape[0] * (self.resize_scale + 4)), int(bw.shape[1] * self.resize_scale))
        resize = cv2.resize(bw, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

        #process = unsharp_mask(resize)
        process1 = cv2.cvtColor( resize, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

        lab= cv2.cvtColor(process1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
        l_channel, a, b = cv2.split(lab)

        # Applying CLAHE to L-channel
        # feel free to try different values for the limit and grid size:
        clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
        cl = clahe.apply(l_channel)

        # merge the CLAHE enhanced L-channel with the a and b channel
        limg = cv2.merge((cl,a,b))

        # Converting image from LAB Color model to BGR color spcae
        enhanced_img = cv2.cvtColor(limg, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
        process2 = cv2.cvtColor(enhanced_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        #sharpen_filter = np.array([[0, -1, 0], [-1, 5, -1], [0, -1, 0]])
        #kernel = np.array([[-1,-1,-1], [-1,9,-1], [-1,-1,-1]])
        #sharped_img = cv2.filter2D(resize, -1, kernel)
        #print(type(resize))
        sharpened_img = cv2.bilateralFilter(process2,9,75,75)
        thresh, im_bw = cv2.threshold(sharpened_img, 130, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY )
        eroded = thin_font(im_bw)
        #cv2.imwrite("outputsharpened.png", sharpened_img)
        #cv2.imwrite("outputbinaryfilter.png", im_bw)
        #cv2.imwrite("outputeroded.png",eroded)
        data = ""
        if general2 == "true" or not melee=="True" or not melee=="False": #or melee=="False"
            data = pytesseract.image_to_string(eroded, config="--psm 6")
        else:
            data = pytesseract.image_to_string(sharpened_img, config="--psm 6")


        return data

print("hi im python\n")
print(sys.argv[0] + "\n" + sys.argv[1] + "\n" + sys.argv[2] + "\n" + sys.argv[3] + "\n" + sys.argv[4])
parser = ImageParser()
parser.parse_screenshot(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[3], sys.argv[4])
```

It is basically a PyTesseract python script that reads text from images. If this could be optimized, that would also help a ton.

Comment: Yes, I am targeting .NET 7.0.

Comment: I've edited it to get rid of the scrollbars, but I don't want to keep populating this comments section with formatting suggestions.

Comment: What you do is slow by definition. Starting another process is always more expensive than  using a thread. Starting one process per file is always more expensive than starting 1 process for N files, precisely due to the process creation overhead. Using a thread to start other processes has no advantage - each process has its own threads. You just add overhead by using extra threads or tasks

Comment: You won't get any answers if people can't even read your code. What is evident is that the application is doing something slow. If you post what the *Python* code does too, it may be possible to fix both applications so they run fast.

Comment: For example, why use Python at all? And if you really need to use Python, why not start, eg just 4 processes and feed filenames to their standard input stream? To really use asynchronous operations you'll have to use `asyncio` in Python. The C# code only starts the remote operations and feeds them data.

Comment: Another option may be to have the C# code save N file lists on disk then start N Python processes to process each file. You avoid the (slight) complexity of working with input streams. You still need to use `asyncio` in Python to avoid expensive blocking

Comment: Apologies Theodor, I thought the comments section is usually for clarification about the question, not necessarily about formatting.

Comment: Yet another way is to use Python's multiprocessing and have Python itself split the work. Be *VERY CAREFUL* though - Python has a very high overhead and can easily end up toasting your CPU doing far less work than C#. I found that out the hard way when I tried to use multiprocessing on a 6-core to process 100 CSV files.

Comment: Panagiotis, you're absolutely correct, I will post the python code, but it is because I want to read text from an image using PyTesseract, and I do not know if there are suitable replacements in C#. If you have a suggestion on a C# OCR tool, please feel free to share.

Comment: @Peter formatting is about the question. Unreadable questions get no answers. Right now, the code is using techniques that have no effect on the problem itself. Processes have their own independent threads, so nothing the main process does will affect the Python processes

Comment: There are a lot of [Tesseract NuGet packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=tesseract). The [most popular one](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/) has 1.8M downloads. You *can* use Python, just not by starting 1 process per file.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I will try out the C# Tesseract NuGet packages and see if I can reduce the overhead by using them, but I'm not exactly hopeful about them being faster than the python method. Guess it's because it's been a long week trying to figure out how to work anything... :(

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I never knew that processes have their own independent threads. That would absolutely explain why anything I've tried has failed. Would there be a way to wait until the Process threads have finished in order to block program execution?

Comment: *Reducing* the number of processes/threads will improve performance. If your machine has 4 cores you can't get it to execute 8 threads at the same time. 4 will be active, 4 will wait to get executed. Starting more processes than you have cores will result in wasted CPU time as threads get scheduled or evicted from cores.

Comment: So what you're saying is having fewer, faster threads would dramatically increase performance?

Comment: Processes own threads, not the other way around. A process gets executed by one thread, which may start others. You can wait for a process to finish before starting another with `Process.WaitForExit` *but* you'd get better performance if you used a loop in Python to call `parser.parse_screenshot` once for each filename in a list.

Comment: `fewer threads would increase performance?` Yes, because there would be less conflict between them. A thread needs a core to run, which means you can't run more threads at a time than there are cores.

Comment: Ok, I will try to send a list to python instead of calling it over and over again to lessen the overhead. However, it's getting really late so I will sleep soon. Thank you so much for the knowledge, I legitmately had 0 idea about the relationships of threads and processes and all that.